# Link to "Open with Windows Explorer" on SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, listview, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a button which redirect users to "Explorer view" in SharePoint 2010. The problem is : i don't know how to get the url of the original button "Open With Windows Explorer". I tested many things without success, like Process.Start("explorer.exe","url of documents library")

Comment: `<a href='#' onClick = "javascript:CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', 'http://sp2010found/sites/test/Shared Documents', '_blank');"> Name </a>`

Comment: Note: It's Works only on IE

Answer (score 9):

1. Within your browser go to the Sharepoint project site and click on the button with the label **Open with Explorer**.
2. Within Windows Explorer, right click on a folder of your project site and select **Create Shortcut**.
3. Right click on the new shortcut and select **properties**
4. On the tab **shortcut** under **target** you can find the URL you need.

In my case the two target shortcuts look like this

> **Internet Explorer:** https://COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com/sites/LIBRARY
>
> **Windows Explorer:** \\COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\LIBRARY

I am on *Office 365 Sharepoint 2013* and on a *Windows 7* machine.

With the following HTML you can open this URL with a button:

```
<input 
    type="button"
    onclick="window.open( 'file:\\\\COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com@SSL\\DavWWWRoot\\sites\\LIBRARY' )"
    value="Explore"
/>
```

In case your URL contains any spaces you need to encode them as **%20**, for other encodings see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

**Update:** Within Windows Explorer the `\\COMPANYNAME.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\LIBRARY` need to be added to "Quick Access" section (top left hand side). Otherwise the solution is not persistent.

Comment: Absolutely works fantastically! The solution I had before this was something like `file://site/library/`, but it was ___EXTREMELY___ slow. Using the `@SSL\DavWWWRoot\library` notation works almost instantly. Great!

Comment: Does this still work? The link didn't work for me in the Windows Explorer address bar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same method as the SharePoint ribbon:

```
<a onclick="CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', '/MyDocLibrary', '_blank');">Open with Explorer</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CoreInvoke function worked PERFECTLY (thanks AleNom!).

I created a function that will dynamically open Explorer from wherever your are on the SharePoint site.  I'm calling it from a custom button I put in the toolbar (masterpage).

```
function openExplorer()
{

if(getQueryString("RootFolder")!="")
{
    var strURL = getQueryString("RootFolder")
}
else
{
    var strURL = top.location.href.replace("http://[servername]","")
    var intLastSlash = strURL.lastIndexOf("/")
    strURL = strURL.substring(0,intLastSlash)
}


if (strURL.lastIndexOf("/Forms") >-1)
{
    strURL = strURL.substring(0,strURL.lastIndexOf("/Forms"))   
}

CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', strURL, '_blank')

}

function getQueryString(name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to translate the library url:

> **from** `http://sharepoint/library`
>
> **to** `\\sharepoint\library`

then you can use a HTML input control with javascript to open the library in an Explorer Window:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('file:\\\\sharepoint\\library')" value="Explore"/>
```

There are security issues involved with calling a local executable directly from a web browser window.